# How to apply surface magnetism on toolbar?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, mrtk

I created a **body-locked toolbar** like in this gif ([link to better quality](https://gfycat.com/handycaninebasilisk)). Therefore I used the scripts **Solver Handler** and the **Solver Body Lock**: 
 [image]

Now I want that this toolbar collides with the environment and does not go through walls, because right now my toolbar goes through everthing. I read that you have to use the **Solver Surface Magnetism** but the only thing I found are guides to align an object to the surface so it sticks to it. But thats not what I want. Here is an example with the HoloLens menu, how it behaves ([link to better quality](https://gfycat.com/concernedsorecricket)):
[image]

**My Question**: How can I achieve that my toolbar behaves like the menu of the hololens, so it does not go through walls/environment?

Comment: I tried to do on this once a couple years ago. It was never satisfactory. You have three competing issues: don't move when the gaze is nearby, do move when it isn't, and avoid RW geometry. Its a PITA trying to balance those factors.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can change the `Orientation Mode` in the Surface Magnetism solver to `None` to achieve the effect your are looking for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something to do this already in MRTK but I'm not sure... 
I'll have to do something like that soon and I was thinking of implementing some logic myself, maybe use one ray from each corner of the toolbar towards the camera and if any hits the space mapping layer adjust the position until all four corners are visible or something of the sort... search a suitable position and Lerp the position there maybe?

Comment: The behaviors of the shell objects ("start" menu, holograms, other windows) and a whole lot of other stuff (like the gaze ring) are (sadly) not exposed to developers.

Comment: On the other hand, it looks like it's already finished and given to the developer. At least that's how it's presented on some pages. But I haven't managed it yet with the given scripts like Solver Handler and Solver Surface Magnitism.